# Can't access model attributes from Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js, pug

I'm walking into a large `Backbone.js` project so I'm still getting my bearings. My template, `my-group-item.jhbs` has:

```
{{#if isComplete}}
.row-fluid
  .span2
    img.entity-image(src="/pictures/{{entityId}}.png")

  .span10
    .row-fluid
      .span12
        h3 {{entityName}}
        p My first variable {{totalFirst}} and my second variable {{totalValue}}

{{/if}}
```

My `View` is:

```
module.exports = class MyItemView extends View
  className: ->
    templateData = @getTemplateData()
    primaryData = @model.get('primaryData')
  tagName: 'li'
  template: require 'views/my-group-item'

  initialize: () ->
    super
    primaryData = @model.get('primaryData')
```

In my template, the `totalFirst` and `totalValue` variables show nothing.

I'm calling my view with:

```
  @groupView = new MyItemView
    collection: groups
    el: '.group-list'
```

How can I get these to show in the template?

Comment: Do you see `entityName` but not the others? How do you pass the model to your template? Are those properties defined in the model?

Comment: I do see `entityName`, but not the others. I'm not sure how the properties are defined in the model. How can I check?

Comment: Ahhh -okay. I see that the fields I want are children of `primaryData` in the model. So how do I access the children in the template?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ primaryData.totalFirst }}`?

Comment: Tried. That doesn't work. `totalFirst` is an attribute in `primaryData` I think. So I'd have to use `.get(`, which doesn't work on the template.

Comment: If I do `{{ primaryData }}` in my view, I get `[object Object]`

Comment: Can you please `console.log(primaryData );` and paste the whole code of your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass more than 1 variable to your template, the first being your model and the second being the attributes of primaryData.